# Log gas / compute usage in anchor program test

Tags: anchor, solana-program, lamports

What is the canonical method for logging the amount of SOL used in a transaction? I'm writing some anchor tests and wanted to get some understanding of which transactions / fns incur more costs than others.

Ideally if you could provide TS/JS code example, or a reference to a code block, that would be super helpful!

Comment: Unless the transaction involves you manipulating Sol in accounts, the transaction fee is .000005 Sol per signature.  There are no gas fees, but you get a maximum of 1.4 million compute units per transaction.

Answer (score 1):

When fetching a transaction either with `getTransaction` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettransaction or as part of a block in `getBlock` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getblock, both fields are populated in the response:

- `result.meta.fee`: the fee paid, in lamports
- `result.meta.computeUnitsConsumed`: the compute units used by the transaction

Answer (score 0):

Transaction fee in Solana are not like EVM’s gas model.

For Solana there only a limit amount of compute you can use for a transaction.

And if you don’t use all of the compute units, will still not refund the rest.

For more detail you can see the [official documentation](https://docs.solana.com/transaction_fees#calculating-transaction-fees).